# Async problem with telethon.sync.TelegramClient and pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

First, I have to develop Telegram Bot that checks if user subscribed to the channel. I use `pyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.6` to create a bot and `Telethon==1.9.0` to check is user subscribed.

I have `@bot.message_handler` where I call global instance of my Class with `telethon.sync` functions. It looks like:

```py
from telebot import TeleBot
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import config  # my module with constants


class TeleHelper:
    def __init__(self, api_id, api_hash, phone, channel, session_name='session'):
        self._client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
        self._client.connect()
        self._setup(phone)
        self._channel = channel

    def _setup(self, phone):  # just setup
        if not self._client.is_user_authorized():
            self._client.send_code_request(phone)
            self._client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

    @staticmethod
    def get_target(user):  # get username or full name
        if user.username:
            return user.username
        else:
            return user.first_name + (f' {user.last_name}' if user.last_name else '')

    def check_subscription(self, user):  # search user in channel members, there is a problem
        target = self.get_target(user)
        participants = self._client.iter_participants(self._channel, search=target)
        ids = [member.id for member in participants]
        return user.id in ids


bot = TeleBot(config.bot_token)  # bot instance
tg = TeleHelper(config.api_id, config.api_hash, config.phone, config.channel)  # instance of the class above


@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def handle_join(message):
    if tg.check_subscription(message.from_user):  # here problems start
        text = 'All is good!'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    else:
        text = 'You have to subscribe @python_lounge'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

I have imported `TelegramClient` from `telethon.sync` not from telethon so that everything looks fine, but accidentally I got an error:

```
2019-08-24 10:31:07,342 (main.py:65 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "RuntimeError occurred, args=('You must use "async for" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ContestBot/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 99, in handle_join
    if tg.check_subscription(message.from_user):
  File "/root/ContestBot/main.py", line 25, in check_subscription
    ids = [member.id for member in participants]
  File "/root/ContestBot/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/requestiter.py", line 102, in __iter__
    'You must use "async for" if the event loop '
RuntimeError: You must use "async for" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")
"
```

I have tried to make "async for", but I am newbie in async programming, there what I wrote:

```
async def check_subscription(self, user):
    ids = []
    async for member in self._client.iter_participants(self._channel, search=self.get_target(user)):
        await ids.append(member.id)

    return user.id in ids
```

Obviously I got wanting, but program still doesn't work:

```
<coroutine object TeleHelper.check_subscription at 0x7ff9bc57f3c8>
/root/ContestBot/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py:59: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TeleHelper.check_subscription' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I use Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My trouble was that I mixed `threads` and `asyncio` without deep understanding. One of the solutions is to use async module such as `aiogram` or even `telethon` to manage the bot.

Actually, I didn't have to use telethon to check is user subscribed to the channel as well. There is a method in `Bot API` called `getChatMember` so that `pyTelegramBotAPI` is enough. It returns `None` or `ChatMember` object with `status` which can be “creator”, “administrator”, “member”, “restricted”, “left” or “kicked”.

So, there is my solution with only `pyTelegramBotAPI`:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Участвовать')
def handle_join(message):
    member = bot.get_chat_member(config.channel_id, message.from_user.id). # right way to check if user subscribed

    if member is not None and member.status in ('creator', 'administrator', 'member'):
        text = 'All is good!'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    else:
        text = 'You have to subscribe @python_lounge'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```

By the way, I found out that `telethon.sync` isn't real. It is just a small hack for people who don't know how asyncio works. So that `telethon.sync` only works in limited cases and you shouldn't and probably can't use it for anything except quick scripts.